# Disable/skip show()

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am writing a script to generate a number of plots from data, each plot first being saved with `plt.savefig()`, then shown by `plt.show()`.
In the first phase I want all plots to be shown and the script to be stopped for each plot, to allow for tweaking of e.g. the axis limits, scale, labels.

In the second phase, when I am including these plots in LaTex and finishing the layout, I want all plots just to be saved to pdf without them popping up when I re-execute the script for final edits.

Is there a simple command I can put up front in my script that disables `plt.show()` so the script can just run in the background in this second phase?

I know I can use `plt.ion()` to make `plt.show()` nonblocking, but that keeps popping up windows that take away my focus from my latex editor window (I'm on Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You arn't asking quite the right question, but to understand the answer you need to understand a bit about the architecture of `matplotlib`.  There is `pyplot` which is a state-machine based layer built to work with ipython to mimic a `MATLAB` like experience.  That is built on top of an `OO` interface (which you really should be using for scripts, instead of `pyplot`, but I digress).  The `OO` layer knows how to draw to a `canvas` and how to convert data -> abstract pretty lines.  The `canvas` is provided by one of a variety of backends, which know how to turn abstract pretty lines -> actual pretty lines.  By default, you are probably using the `GTKAgg` backend or the `TKAgg` backend, which draw the lines to a canvas embedded in a gui and are both interactive backends.

You just need to use a non-interactive backend the second time through.

In your script include:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('PDF')
```

before importing `pyplot`, and comment that line out when you want the interactive figures.

Comment: Thank you, this works! And I have a decent understanding of matplotlib's structure but would not have figured this out.

Comment: I use `plt.tight_layout()` and this gives a small warning: `tight_layout : falling back to Agg renderer`. But plot looks the same so I can ignore it.